# Elements of 'links' HTMLcollection display as undefined

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

So I'm writing a basic chrome extension that grabs all of the links (anchors) from a page and then gets the InnerHTML element of the first one. The extension is using a content_script javascript file that has `"run_at"` set to `"document_start"`.

This is my (pared down) code:

```
console.log(document.links);
console.log(document.links[0].innerHTML);
```

When this runs, in the console it posts

```
> [item: function, namedItem: function]
> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of undefined
```

However, the first line can be expanded and when it is expanded, it reveals all of the elements that I am trying to use. Does anyone have any idea why it's not letting me use the elements of the HTMLcollection and yet it will still display them to me?

I have tried using `document.links[0]` and `document.links.item(0)` to the same error message.

Edit: The main problem here, regardless of innerHTML, is that `document.links[0]` is undefined, and I don't know why that is.

Comment: Did you try `document.querySelector('a').innerHTML`

Comment: another snag: document.links also find <link> tags, which are self-closed and thus have no innerHTML.

Comment: @adeneo `console.log(document.querySelector('a').innerHTML)` gives the error message `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of null`

Comment: @dandavis it's not even getting that far though, as document.links[0] is undefined

Comment: set `run_at` to `document_end`

Comment: @turner—the *links* collection is live, so it doesn't matter when you get it, only when you read it. So you could do `var links = document.links` in the head, and then when ever links are added to the document, they will be added to the collection (and removed if they are removed from the document).